# Получение нескольких данных с сайта

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Использую библиотеку "htmlagility" для парсинга данных с сайта. Как с помощью одного запроса xpath получить несколько данных? Каждое поле находится в других классах.
Не уверена, что тут можно закреплять ссылку на пример сайта, но я попробую. Пример сайта "https://www.farfetch.com/ru/shopping/men/new-balance-997-item-14986965.aspx". Необходимо одним запросом получить "New Balance", "кроссовки 997", "10 567" и "7925".

Была идея брать с сайта "div", содержащий в себе эти данные и потом по отдельности парсить этот div.

Comment: Хотите фокус? [Смотрите](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G68o9j), а еще и [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TooVO.png). Вы не хотите думать как разработчик, подумайте хорошенько, как должен работать сайт, рассчитанный на огромную аудиторию, да еще и на кучу стран. Наверно он не генерирует постоянно себе HTML, верно? Наверно у нег есть где-то данные в удобно читаемом для него виде? Данная вами страница содержит в себе целый кладезь данных в виде JSON, так почему не взять его?

Comment: А как Вы определили, что сайт хранит данные в формате json?

Comment: Просто посмотрев его исходный код?)

Comment: Вы мне скинули второй скрин. Это доп. утилита?

Comment: Это [сайт](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/), который приводит JSON к читаемому виду.

Comment: Вы знаете что такое JSON? Это формат, со своим синтаксисом, который начинается с `{` и заканчивается `}`, внутри имеет `"имя": "значение"`, где значение может быть числом (`"value": 123 `), массивом (`"value": [  ]`), строкой (`"value": "hello"`), bool (`"value": true`), вот это все JSON, отдельный формат данных, который очень удобно обрабатывать програмно. Сайт, который я дал, разбирает этот формат, выводя в удобном древовидном виде все данные, по которым нам с вами легко его понять. Так что если вы вставите туда валидный JSON, то лишь узнаете что в них.

Comment: Да, знаю, но я не могу найти на сайте файл, содержащий в себе данные в формате json. Утилиту, которую Вы мне скинули обрабатывает только протоколы http.

Comment: Повторюсь, она не ищет JSON в коде, она лишь выводит готовый, валидный формат в удобном виде. Данные на предоставленном вами сайте прям [в коде](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am7Vj.png), ищите внимательней.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Сейчас попробую